# SqlDependency causes error in other application

Tags: sql-server, sqldependency

I have a project where I need to monitor changes in a 3rd party database.

SqlDependency seem like a good solution but it causes the following error in the 3rd party application.

> INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect
>   settings: 'ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that
>   SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on
>   computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications
>   and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

(The application works fine when my test program below is not running)

What SET options does this refer to?

The only set operation I have done is `ALTER DATABASE TestDb SET ENABLE_BROKER` to enable notifications.

I also did:

```
CREATE QUEUE ContactChangeMessages;

CREATE SERVICE ContactChangeNotifications
    ON QUEUE ContactChangeMessages
    ([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification]);
```

Here is my Linqpad test code which works fine if I insert/update/delete records in management studio.

```
void Main() {
    const string cs = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=True";

    var are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(cs)) {
        connection.Open();
        SqlDependency.Start(cs);
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT orderNo FROM dbo.Orders WHERE ProductNo = '111'";

            var dep = new SqlDependency(cmd, null, 60);
    dep.OnChange += (s,e) => { 
                Console.WriteLine(e.Info);
                are.Set();
            };
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                while (reader.Read()) {
                }
            }
            are.WaitOne();
            SqlDependency.Stop(cs);
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know, and can not change, how the 3rd part app connects to the database. I can run the sql profiler if more information is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers exactly to the SET options mentioned in the error message:

> SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER,
>   ANSI_PADDING'.

The correct settings, along with other restrictions, are described in [Creating a Query for Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> When a SELECT statement is executed under a notification request, the
>   connection that submits the request must have the options for the
>   connection set as follows:
>
> ```
> ANSI_NULLS ON
> ANSI_PADDING ON
> ANSI_WARNINGS ON
> CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
> QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
> NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
> ARITHABORT ON
> ```
>
> Note Note
>
> Setting ANSI_WARNINGS to ON implicitly sets ARITHABORT to ON when the
>   database compatibility level is set to 90. If the database
>   compatibility level is set to 80 or earlier, the ARITHABORT option
>   must explicitly be set to ON.

These settings are affected by:

- the current database settings, which can be viewed in [`sys.databases`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx)
- the session settings, which can be viewed in [`sys.dm_exec_sessions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx)
- by procedure/trigger create settings, which can be viewed using [`OBJECTPROPERTY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176105.aspx).

You need to find which property from the ones mentioned in the error message is non-conforming and why (probably is a database setting). Most likely is a 80 compatibility level set on the database.

Update. Nevermind that, you say that you can successfully create a query notification but then the application itself fails. The application must be explicitly setting one of these settings OFF on it's connection (you can validate by inspecting sys.dm_exec_sessions). You must contact the application vendor, seems like she is very explicitly (albeit probably unintentionally) making his application incompatible with query notifications.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand that the query must run with the same options as the notification request. The application does explicitly set some of these to off.

Comment: The sql dependency connection is the one that needs the SET ARITHABORT ON . Using a 3rd party database means I am hesitant to set the database level value to the appropriate value. I am still research if it is possible to grant a default value for a specific user.